# Вопрос по абсолютному позиционированию элемента

Tags: html, css, position, позиционирование

Всем привет! Может быть кто-нить подскажет, почему абсолютное позиционирование элемента в блоке в chrome и firefox начинается с центра, а в opere и ie с начала?
Разметка, если поможет:

```css
.vc_row-fluid [class*="vc_span"]:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.vc_row-fluid .vc_span3, .wpb_teaser_grid.wpb_carousel .vc_span3 {
  width: 23.5%;
}
.vc_row-fluid [class*="vc_span"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.mile-content:first-child {
  border: none;
}
.mile-content {
  border-left: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
.counter_holder.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.counter_holder {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity .4s ease 0s;
}
.entertain {
   position: relative;
 }
.entertain .counter_holder span.counter {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 25px;
color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.counter_holder span.counter {
  font-family: "Oswald",sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #1e9944;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block!important;
  height: 70px;
}
.mile-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
}
.mile-title p {
  margin: 0;
}
.primary-typo {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
p {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.vc_row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
}
.wpb_row {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entertain .counter_holder.center:before {
content: "\a0";
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid entertain" style="text-align:center">
<div class="vc_span3 wpb_column column_container">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">

        <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="mile-content" id="mile-1">
              <div class="mile-description">
                <div class="mile-icon">
                  <i class="ion-ios-cloudy-night-outline medium-icon"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="counter_holder center" style="opacity: 1;"><span class="counter zero executed" style="color:#000000; font-size:30px; height:30px; line-height:30px;">52</span>
            </div>
            <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
              <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="mile-title text-center">
                  <p class="primary-typo">Бессонных часов</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: А у какого из этих блоков задано абсолютное позиционирование?

Comment: добавил в сообщение стили

Comment: проверил в Опере 12.17, Опере 28.0 и ИЕ10-9 все по центру отображается

Comment: Не вижу элемента с классом entertrain — в результате стили для «.entertain .counter_holder span.counter» не работают и никаких элементов с абсолютным позиционированием по-прежнему нет (а если «.entertrain» из стилей стереть, то всё едет)

Comment: для класса entertain стили 
.entertain{
 position:relative;
}
ну вы же, надеюсь, понимаете, что код вырван из контекста. построен на wordpress

Comment: Ну вырывать-то из контекста надо без поломки) От дописывания стиля в CSS элемент в html-коде не появится, а где он там должен быть — нам неведомо.

Comment: добавил код в html - так понятнее будет?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s75pbkw0/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s75pbkw0/1/ - почищенный вариант (в плане разметки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сокращённый код, на котором воспроизводится проблема:
http://jsfiddle.net/s75pbkw0/10/

```
<div class="entertain">
    <div class="counter_holder center">
        <span class="counter">52</span>
    </div>
</div>

.counter_holder.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.entertain {
  position: relative;
}

.counter {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Сам не мог сократить?

---

А решается так:
http://jsfiddle.net/s75pbkw0/13/

```
<div class="entertain">
    <div class="counter_holder center">
        &nbsp;<span class="counter">52</span>&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Первый nbsp - чтобы заработало, второй - чтобы сохранить центрирование.

Comment: "Сам не мог сократить?"
нет, не могу - структура html создается с помощью visual composer в wordpress, соответственно ни сократить, ни засунуть внутрь nbsp не могу- могу только на стили как-то влиять... так что вопрос по-прежнему открыт: либо кто-нить подскажет, как можно решить проблему только с помощью стилей, либо ответит на вопрос почему в chrome и firefox позиционирование начинается с центра, а в opere и ie с начала?

Comment: добавил картинки для наглядности:
так выглядит в chrome и firefox 
http://s019.radikal.ru/i633/1504/f6/060552aefbb9.png
так в opere и ie
http://s017.radikal.ru/i408/1504/45/b004955577f4.png

Comment: @Вася, при чём тут как она создаётся? Перед размещением вопроса надо оставлять как меньше кода, чтобы другим было проще разобраться. Почему позиционирование с начала? Да потому что текста нет и они не задумались, что надо брать текуюую позицию в центре, а не в нуле.

Comment: Уффф!.. удалось этого добиться с помощью css: 
.entertain .counter_holder.center:before {
 content: "\a0";
}
Спасибо за подсказку, заочно ставлю ответ решенным. Здесь несколько неочевидных штук, может быть кому-нить пригодится